# Show mysql data in a dynamic image

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a dynamic user stat's signature.

Here's my code: **UPDATED**

```
<?php
//Send a generated image to the browser
$config->Host = 'localhost';
$config->User = 'grpg';
$config->Pass = 'E8vspAcP';
$config->DB   = 'grpg_wp';;

$con = mysql_connect($config->Host,$config->User,$config->Pass);
if (!$con) die('<div class="errorbox">Nepavyko prisijungti prie duomenu bazes: '. mysql_error() .'</div>');

mysql_select_db($config->DB, $con);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM serverplayers WHERE id=1");
$showuser = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$user1 = $showuser['User'];
$user="$user1";  // or the value from your database
create_image($user);

function create_image($user)
{
    //Set the image width and height
    $width = 100;
    $height = 20;

    //Create the image resource
    $image = ImageCreate($width, $height);

    //We are making three colors, white, black and gray
    $white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $black = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $grey = ImageColorAllocate($image, 204, 204, 204);

    //Make the background black
    ImageFill($image, 0, 0, $black);

    //Add randomly generated string in white to the image
    ImageString($image, 3, 30, 3, "$user", $white);
    //Tell the browser what kind of file is come in
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

    //Output the newly created image in jpeg format
    ImageJpeg($image);

    //Free up resources
    ImageDestroy($image);
}
?>
```

If I change this: `$pass = "$user";` to this `$pass = "erlis";` my username displays with no problem. What's the deal here? The image is displaying nicely but without no text.Can't figure it out...

Comment: What does `var_dump( $show['User'] );` output?

Answer (score 3):

`$show['User'];` is not in the scope of that function. You need to pass that to your function

```
function create_image($user) 
{
  //.....
}
```

And, call your function after populating your variable, not before!

```
$user="test";  // or the value from your database
create_image($user);
```

Comment: loll, when you have `exit()` as your first PHP statement then what else to expect? rest of your code won't be executed. Remove that exit() and try again

Comment: Okay, another UPDATE, this time I think I did everything right, but now I get the broken image icon...
UPDATE: Found out that if I take out all of the mysql connection thins and stuff, and just leave `$user="erlis";` ir works perfectly fine.

Comment: Your new code works very well for me, just check what's the value of `$user1` before you call your function?

Comment: No leave the MySQL stuff in, otherwise whats the use if it doesn't serve your purpose. Just check if the value from MySQL is what you expect? is $user1 populated correctly?

Comment: I think theres something wrong with my SQL query because if I change the variable `$user="$user1";` to `$user="erlis";` it still doesn't work.Without the SQL stuff it does..

Comment: But what's the output of `echo $user1;` ?

Comment: Wont let me. Broken image and that's it.Maybe im putting the `echo` in the wrong place?Just after the `$user` ?

Comment: echo is fine, just need to see if your database is returning something or no and that's it